# Ubuntu 16.04 won't install on VirtualBox (14.04 works fine)

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I can only get Ubuntu 16.04 on my system (macos ~2010 running latest OS) if I first install 14.04 and then upgrade it.

I'm using the latest version of VirtualBox for Mac. It seems to be limited to ubuntu flavors. I've tried ubuntu, xubuntu and ubuntu-gnome. Latest Kali installs fine (which is debian based).

Here's what I get when I first boot up from ISO:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to get to the option menu where you can choose to try or install Ubuntu?

Comment: Nope. Not on 16.04 -- I can on 14.04. As soon as the live .iso boots up I get that messed up screen pictured in 16.04. I'm wondering if there's some display adapter setting in virtualbox I need to able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching video consoles solves the problem. When you see the graphics screen that you illustrate, hit:

**control-alt-f1** followed by **control-alt-f7**

I've also seen one person using:

**rightctrl-f1** followed by **rightctrl-f7**

update: since the user has changed the default Virtualbox hot key from rightctrl to leftcommand, this particular user would have to type leftcommand-f1 followed by leftcommand-f7.

Let us know which one works for you. Cheers, Al

Comment: The correct combination for Virtualbox is the second, unless the user has changed the default **right-ctrl** function with another key.  The **ctrl-alt** combination affects the host system if it's Linux.  Judging from what I see on the image though, if we take a look at the lower right corner, the key is assigned to **left-something**.  It's not **right-ctrl** either.

Comment: is there someway to just change this in virtualbox before I start the .iso?

Comment: don't know what i did wrong. on a mac, ctrl is not ctrl on windows. and i have a fn key. i tried but now i just have a black screen.

Comment: This worked: `fn+alt+cmd+f1` -- I didn't need `f7`